# Installing OS via USB flash drive results in "Reboot and select proper boot device"

Tags: boot, windows-10, usb, uefi, bootable-media

When I attempt to boot the newly built computer from a USB flash drive in order to install windows 10, I get the error "Reboot and select proper boot device." I think that somehow my settings in the UEFI are not correct so that it is not attempting to boot from the USB flash drive as I'd like.

Some details:

- Motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-H81M-HD3
- I created the bootable USB flash drive from an ISO file on a Mac, using the Terminal & this method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nhgjqbq_zYA
- This question is similar to mine, but doesn't seem to have a solution I can try, as I do not have a windows machine. I'd really like to solve this with the machines I have at hand if at all possible. [Can't install OS with bootable USB — Reboot and select proper boot device](https://superuser.com/questions/778648/cant-install-os-with-bootable-usb-reboot-and-select-proper-boot-device) [edited to add- I have a MacBook Air running Yosemite 10.10.5 & a new PC that is the focus of this question, which doesn't yet have an OS.]

Comment: Are you sure your USB is bootable? Have you entered the settings in UEFI to look at the boot order?

Comment: I have been trying to find the boot settings in the UEFI, but am not finding the boot order. Do you know where it might be?

Comment: Once I do find the right place in the UEFI-- Is the idea that if the USB isn't bootable, I won't see it in the list for the boot order?

Comment: it varies, but it's usually pretty obviously labeled "boot order". there should only be so many tabs to check

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to `dd` a Windows ISO to a USB drive. It's simply not supposed to be bootable this way. For the PC to boot a USB drive, the drive needs to have either a MBR with proper boot code for hard disks, but not ISO9660/UDF, for BIOS/CSM, or a proper FAT-formatted ESP for UEFI.

The simplest way to make a bootable Windows installation USB for UEFI, is to format the drive with FAT32, and then mount the ISO and copy the content to it. UEFI simply looks for EFI binaries on proper location.

However, since the offical ISO from Microsoft have been consisting of file (well the "core" file, namely install.wim) that exceeds the 4G file limit of FAT32, meaning that you'll need to use NTFS or exFAT instead.

But then by standard UEFI firmwares are only required to support the FAT-family filesystems (not including exFAT), therefore solutions like Rufus ships an NTFS/exFAT UEFI driver and a program that loads it before executing the boot file on the "main" NTFS/exFAT partition. (Binary build of the driver is also available separately, which can be loaded with EDK2 shell instead.) Another alternative would be to have a FAT(32) ESP with grub, which can chainload the boot file on the main partition as well.

Some UEFI firmware (AFAIK, AMI Aptio ones) consists of NTFS driver. For such firmware you don't need any kind of FAT32 ESP.

For the record, the Media Creation Tool from Microsoft seems to work around the problem by using the more compressed ESD format instead of WIM for the `install` image, which is why it allows you to continue using FAT32 only. (I have no idea whether Microsoft has trim down some content of the image or it really purely relies on compression though.)

Comment: Thank you, this sounds promising! Can you walk me through it in a bit more detail?  I wipe the usb, and then, how would you suggest I format it to FAT32 & mount the ISO to it?

Comment: Use any tool you like to put FAT32 on it. You don't mount the `.iso` file to the disk; you mount the `.iso` file and then copy the files from within the `.iso` file to the USB drive. A tool like [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) can help automate the process -- although I've never used Rufus to make a bootable USB from a Windows installation disc, so it might not be the right tool.

Comment: Rufus worked for my BIOS system

Comment: I ended up finding a windows machine and learning that my ISO file was corrupted, but this is the advice that would have worked if it wasn't corrupted so I'm marking it accepted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just a heads-up, it looks like NTFS might be required for recent builds. FAT will boot, but eventually there's an error.

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer. iso burn using dd is 100% reliable for any OS. The correct smart boot and UEFI opinions need to be turned on in the BIOS in older machines. Nothing to do with dd. dd only fails if you use of=/dev/sdb1 or whatever target is. must be of=/dev/sdb

Comment: @EamonnKenny If you say so. Have fun trying to boot from a USB drive without MBR or ESP. It isn't even about dd, but the form of the image that got written.

Answer (score 4):

Annoyingly some USB drives aren't boot compatible with some computers and the only way to find out is try several USB drives, do you have any others to try, Sandisk seems to to good here?

Comment: Did you mean to put this as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: interesting...I could try that.

Comment: I've found this to be true for BIOS-mode boots. I have yet to encounter a USB drive that's not bootable in EFI mode, assuming it's got the right files. Since the OP hasn't clearly specified BIOS- or EFI-mode booting, this might or might not be an issue, but it's certainly worth mentioning.

Comment: @EricF This is an answer, not a comment. It benefits the site and future users to have alternate answers, even if they're not "the" answer for the original OP.

Comment: @RodSmith sir you just saved my life... Had the aforementioned problem, changed the setting which forced BIOS mode, now it's apparently working!